# Is there a way to calculate the number of rows by table, schema and catalog in Databricks SQL (Spark SQL)?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I need to create a dashboard inside Databricks that summarizes the number of rows in the current workspace right now.

Is there a way to create a SQL query to calculate the number of rows by table, schema, and catalog? The expected result would be:

| Catalog | Schema | Table | Rows |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| example_catalog_1 | Finance | table_example_1 | 1567000 |
| example_catalog_1 | Finance | table_example_2 | 67000 |
| example_catalog_2 | Procurement | table_example_1 | 45324888 |
| example_catalog_2 | Procurement | table_example_2 | 89765987 |
| example_catalog_2 | Procurement | table_example_3 | 145000 |

Currently, I am working on a pure SQL workflow. So I would like to understand if it's possible to execute such an action using SQL, because as much as I know, the dashboards in Databricks do not accept PySpark Codes.

I was looking for a way to do that. I know that it's possible to access the tables in the workspace by using `system.information_schema.tables` but how to use it to count to total rows for each table presented there?

I was checking that via SQL Server it's possible via `sys schema`, `dynamic query`, or `BEGIN...END` clause. I couldn't find a way in Databricks to do that.

Comment: Hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59228889/azure-databricks-count-rows-in-all-tables-is-there-a-better-way (this code will provide all the details expect catalog)
Note: This is not a SQL query, the code is written in python and later it is converted to a dataframe. You will get the result as tabular format shown above expect catalog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I figured out to build this was by adapting the code suggested by @Sharma. It was needed as I am using Unity Catalog and this change was necessary to iterate over the catalogs.

```
_sql = """
select
  concat_ws('.', table_catalog, table_schema, table_name) as address,
  table_catalog,
  table_schema,
  table_name
from
  system.information_schema.tables as table_list
  inner join (
    select
      catalog_name
    from
      system.information_schema.catalogs
    where
      catalog_name not in ('system')
  ) as table_choose on table_choose.catalog_name = table_list.table_catalog
where
  table_schema <> 'information_schema'
  and table_type <> 'VIEW'
"""

df_result = sqlContext.sql(_sql)
df_pandas = df_result.toPandas()

for index, row in df_pandas.iterrows():
    table_address = row['address']
    print('Calculating for -> ', index +1 , ' - ' , table_address)
    _sql_query = f'select count(*) myrowcnt from {table_address}'
    
    try:
        _tmp_df = spark.sql(_sql_query)
        row_count = _tmp_df.collect()[0]['myrowcnt'] 
        print('>> Result: ', row_count)
        df_pandas.loc[index, 'total_rows'] = row_count

        _size = spark.sql(f"describe detail {table_address}").select("sizeInBytes").collect()[0]['sizeInBytes'] 
        df_pandas.loc[index, 'size_mb'] = _size/1000000
    except:
        print("!!! An error occurred !!!")
        print('Query: ', _sql_query)
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

I strongly doubt if you can run that kind of query in the databricks dashboard . The link shared by @Sharma is more as to how to get the record count using dataframe and not how to link that with the databricks dashboard .